# C program doesn't print out the values

Tags: c, count, linked-list, median

I have a program that is looking for a total numbers and what is the middle number in a linked list. The question that I have is why it doesn't print out the values?

Here is the code:

```
int count(list values){
    if(values == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + count(values->next);
}

void middle(struct node *head){
    int count = 0;
    struct node *mid = head;

    while (head != NULL){
        if(count & 1)
            mid = mid->next;

        count++;
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void traverse(list values){
     if(values->next)
     printf("\n# of the values: %.1f% \nMiddle: %.1f%\n", count, middle);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *input = stdin;

    list values = readNumbers(input);
    traverse(values);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us the whole code, please.

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: list readNumbers (FILE *file){
 list values = NULL, first = NULL;
 int c;
 while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
  int i = 0;
  
  list new = (list) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  
  if (values == NULL) values = new;
  else {
   values->next = new;
   values = new;
  }
  values = new;
  
  if (first == NULL) first = values;
  do {
   values->value[i++] = c;
  } while ((c = getc(file)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
  values->value[i] = '\0';
 }
 return first;
}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know where to start here. I can't really tell what you are trying to do.

But let's look at this line:

```
printf("\n# of the values: %.1f% \nMiddle: %.1f%\n", count, middle);
```

`count` and `middle` are functions, but you are not calling those functions here. You are simply passing the address of those functions to `printf()`, which has no knowledge that these are functions. You need to include parentheses after the function names (`count(args)` and `middle(args)` in order to call those functions.

Comment: Does it work if I pass count(values) or middle(values)

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your code to answer that. But it's your code. You're the one who should be testing it. Did you try it? Did you get a compile error? What is the error?

Comment: I got it for the count.. I'm working on middle now.. I guess that the issue that I'm having now is that middle is the void.. I'll get back if I need more help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\n# of the values: %.1f% \nMiddle: %.1f%\n", count, middle);
```

`count` should receive a parameter (`list` ). The compiler will treat `count` and `middle`, without parameters as function pointers.

Also note that `middle` is a `void` function so what exactly do you want it to print?